# Enter commands to Java runtime cmd prompt

Tags: java, cmd

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
            "cmd",
            "/c",
            "start",
            "cd",
            "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\PROPHET\\PROPHET\\Prophet2012"
            "prpht0912" //shortcut to prpht0912.exe
            "eorinput"  // eorinput.ind, input sheet that prpht0912.exe processes
```

Opens a command prompt to the dir I need.

To execute the program contained in that folder, I then need to execute "prpht0912 eorinput" from the command prompt like:

```
M:\MandNDrives\mwallace\PROPHET\PROPHET\Prophet2012>prpht0912 eorinput
```

However the space in the entry returns an error in the prompt: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Define *tripping things up*

Comment: Are you sure it is the space?  If you are not running from the M: drive, use cd /d

Comment: I've attempted an answer, but am just guessing what your actual problem is based on what I think you're trying to do.  In case I'm wrong, could you edit your question to include the code you've tried and which doesn't work, and a more detailed description of what goes wrong?

Comment: Tripping things up = "The system cannot find the path specified". 
Also, "prpht0912" is a shortcut to "prpht0912.exe", however this program processes an input sheet "eorinput.ind" that is contained in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to execute two commands via the command line in a single invocation of `cmd.exe`: `cmd.exe /c` is followed by a single command, and another `/c` afterwards would be interpreted as a parameter to that command.

Furthermore, invoking it twice won't get you what you want either, as changes of directory are forgotten when the process exits, so the second invocation would be run in the default working directory of the Java process, not the directory you changed to with your first invocation.

Also, it is unfortunate, but Java doesn't provide a way to change the current working directory of its own process.

As far as I can see it, you have two options:

1. Make sure your Java program is started with the working directory set to the one you need your child program to run in
2. Invoke a single `.bat` file that contains both of the commands you need to run.

Comment: While you might not be able to change the working directory of the current application (without some questionable class loader hacking) You most certainly can specify the working directory of a process you launch from within a JVM, by using a ProcessBuilder. He could just create a ProcessBuilder for the application he wishes to launch, and use it to spawn a new Process object. Setting the working directory accordingly.

Comment: I moved the target prpht0912.exe program and components to the java directory I'm using. That solved it. But if/when I need to use multiple directories I will go the ProcessBuilder route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To Execute the following command

```
M:\MandNDrives\mwallace\PROPHET\PROPHET\Prophet2012>prpht0912 eorinput
```

You need the following

```
String[] commands = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\PROPHET\\PROPHET\\Prophet2012\\prpht0912.exe eorinput" };
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Note**

When you pass an array, ProcessBuilder would consider only the first element as program  and remaining as arguments for that program.

```
  String prog = cmdarray[0];
```